# How to do logout react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to make sign out in my project? Also the most ways are don't worked because i put my data to firebase through REST API, please help me. It's Profile.js, where i need to realise the fucntion logOut

```
const Profile = () => {
  const [user] = useAuth()
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const logOut = () => {
This function
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/Logo_small.png')}
                style={styles.logo_s}
                resizeMode='contain'/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.main_cont}>
            <Profile_text marginBottom={28}/>
            <View style={styles.replace}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.inp}
                placeholder={user.displayName}
                placeholderTextColor= 'rgba(207, 77, 79, 0.75)'
                editable={false}/>
              <Pressable onPress={''}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/images/replace_btn.png')}
                  style={styles.replace_btn}
                  resizeMode='contain'/>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
            <UnderLine marginBottom={500}/>
            <Pressable style={styles.result} onPress={logOut}>
                <Text style={styles.text_result}>Выйти из профиля</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
        <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/bottom_menu.png')}
        style={styles.img_bg}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

There is App.js

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Navigator = () => {

  const [user] = useAuth()

  if(!user) {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen  name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }

  return (   
    <NavigationBar/>
  )
}
```

Also i have an a Navigation Bar:

```
<Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarStyle: {
                    height: 80,
                    position:'absolute',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    elevation: 0,
                },
                tabBarLabelStyle: {color: '#000000'}
            }}
            tabBarOptions={{
                showLabel: false,
            }}>
                <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                    <View>
                        <Image
                        source={focused ? require('../assets/images/profile_use.png') : require('../assets/images/profile.png') }
                        style={{
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                        }}
                        resizeMode='contain'/>
                    </View>
                ),
                }}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Train" component={Train} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View>
                            <Image
                            source={focused ? require('../assets/images/train_use.png') : require('../assets/images/train.png') }
                            style={{
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                            }}
                            resizeMode='contain'/>
                        </View>
                    ),
                }}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Statistics" component={Statistics} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View>
                            <Image
                            source={focused ? require('../assets/images/statistic_use.png') : require('../assets/images/statistic.png') }
                            style={{
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                            }}
                            resizeMode='contain'/>
                        </View>
                    ),
                }}/>
            </Tab.Navigator>
```

Please, help me, i'm just beginner in react native. **Again: what need to make logout?**
May be i can't do it because my autorization is in Stack Navigator, but the Profile is in Tab Navigator, pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
const [user, setUser] = useAuth()  

logout = () => {
setUser(false)
}
```

Comment: yaeh, it's really works